# How will you design a proxy server that supports HTTP 1.1 keep-alive completely?

Tags: algorithm, keep-alive, http-1.1

It seems even nginx only half supports HTTP 1.1 keep-alive requests:

> It is an HTTP/1.0 proxy without the
>   ability for keep-alive requests yet.
>   (As a result, backend connections are
>   created and destroyed on every
>   request.) Nginx talks HTTP/1.1 to the
>   browser and HTTP/1.0 to the backend
>   server. As such it handles keep-alive
>   to the browser. ([source](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule))

Were it you,how would you implement this?

The hardest part I think is how to make the response the same order as requested in keep-alive mode.

Comment: I would probably start by gathering statistics on recency of previous requests and request keep-alive with connections sporting a noticable probability of impending reuse - if statistics showed that was common enough, which I doubt.